# Session level and application lvl seqNumber?

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

Does quickfix/j maintain same sequence of seqNum for both type of messages(session and application lvl messages) or each level has separate sequence of seqNum.

Suppose I have a connection running, in  the same time I'm getting orders msgType=D and quickfix session level message heartbeat msgType=0. 
currecnt seqNum of msgType=10, and in the mean while order msgType come in, i want to know what will be the ser number of msgType=D. eother seqNum will be 11 or 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same sequence for all types of messages.

Note that incoming and outgoing, however, each have their own sequence.

Comment: Thanks Grant. 
Also can you please tell me, is there is way to get current seqNum from session not from msg?

Comment: Also you can answer in new thread of answer i'll up vote of that answer as well.

Comment: `session.getExpectedSenderNum()` and `.getExpectedTargetNum()`.  See [here](http://quickfixj.org/quickfixj/javadoc/1.5.3/quickfix/Session.html).  **Though I'm of the opinion that anyone who thinks they need to programmatically interact with sequence numbers is probably wrong.**  In my 5 years of working with QF, I've come across very few good reasons for a program to care about sequence numbers at the application level.

Comment: thanks. i dont to keep message in memory just for latest seqNum that's i want to get it from session.

Comment: I can't think of any good reason to need the sequence number.